# I am developing a quiz app using flutter and node js and need to broadcast a random question to all the participants

Tags: node.js, sockets, flutter

I am developing a quiz app using flutter and node js as backend,where i am trying to broadcast a question to all the participants but i am not aware of how to do this and not getting enough resource regarding this
Any help is highly appreciated
Thank you

I have just started with flutter and watching tutorials

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand, you want to update your clients (connected clients) from server.
In this case, You should implement sockets.
With sockets you can create messaging from server to clients.

Look at this chat Nodejs sample - https://socket.io/get-started/chat/
And for flutter - https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_socket_io

Comment: Suppose there are 10 lakh users.So it possible  implement it using socket?